# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError when iteratiing a nested dictionary in html flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have the following dictionary.

```
parent_dict= {
     "AAA": 19, 
     "BBB": 74861149, 
     "CCC": "84%", 
     "ABC": {
          "Types": {
               "A1": 25
          }
     }, 
     "DEF": {
          "Average": 279, 
          "Types": {
               "B1": 12, 
               "B2": 1500, 
               "B3": 9000
          }, 
          "Total": 46248438
     }
}
```

I want to iterate this nested dictionary in html page. This dictionary is sent through `render_template` in flask python.

I have used python and flask to create a end point and send this to my HTML page.

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/sendData',methods=['GET','POST'])
def sendData():
return render_template('demo.html', parent_dict=parent_dict)
```

**demo.html**

```
{% for key,parent_dict_item in parent_dict.items() %}
{% for key2, nested_value in parent_dict_item.items() %}
<p>{{ parent_dict_item }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am getting this error when I run the URL in chrome.

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
>   UndefinedError: 'int object' has no attribute 'items'

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an if condition to check the type of 'parent_dict_item'. Nested loop will only work if the parent_dict_item is of 'dict' type:

```
{% for key,parent_dict_item in parent_dict.items() %}
    {% if type(parent_dict_item).__name__ == 'dict' %}
        {% for key2, nested_value in parent_dict_item.items() %}
            <p>{{ parent_dict_item }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your nested for loops assume that every second level entry is also a dict, but this is not the case, it breaks on the first item:

```
{% for key,parent_dict_item in parent_dict.items() %}

# key = "AAA", parent_dict_item = 19

{% for key2, nested_value in parent_dict_item.items() %}

# This breaks, because parent_dict_item is 19 (an int) so you can't call int.items().

<p>{{ parent_dict_item }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You'll need to add in conditional logic that defines what you want to do if the parent_dict_item isn't a dict.